# Making JavaDoc robust against refactoring

Tags: java, refactoring, javadoc

I'm working on an application which is constantly refactored to improve it. Now, if we rename a certain class to better capture its intention, all the documentation mentioning the class does not get updated automatically, unless you use links ({@link ClassName}) to refer to the class.

JavaDoc principles however state that one should "Use in-line links economically", since links stand out and draw the readers attention, which I find sensible. Also you can't link to parameters of a method.

Is there another way in JavaDoc to make comments more robust to refactoring I'm not aware of?

Comment: How are you refactoring? When renaming in Eclipse there is option to search through comments.

Comment: Yes, I use Eclipse and I remember having seen that. I don't get the option however (using Ctrl+Alt+R), and I can't find anything in the settings to change that.

Anyways, that would work most times, but it can of course be ambiguous.

Comment: IntelliJ searches through comments, strings and files to find things to rename.  It also offers to rename field, variables and parameters.. I assume Eclipse does the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using eclipse to do refactoring you can search through string references in things like xml files as well.

Press Shift-Alt-R *twice* to get the dialog box.
(On Macs it is Option-Command-R *twice* )

Comment: Thanks! That wasn't what I was really looking for, but I guess it's the best solution out there for me.

Comment: I think, it's Alt+Shift+R now.

Comment: Both won't search in {@link}

Comment: @this - fixed I have a Mac so I was guessing :-)

Comment: @Gangnus - link gets fixed for me. I always go through the preview on renaming and I see the link references changed.

Comment: @Pat - The only means that renaming don't use eclipse search service.

Comment: @Gangnus As for {@link}s, Eclipse processes them even with a single Shift-Alt-R if Javadoc processing is turned on: in the dialog Window -> Preferences go to Java -> Compiler -> Javadoc and check "Process Javadoc comments". (Another effect of that option is that then Eclipse will warn about Javadoc errors.)